# Will 2x8 spruce/pine/fir fencing rails last as long as 2x6 redwood in a hot sunny dry climate?

Tags: wood, fence

Can I expect unpainted, unstained 2x8 or even 2x10 spruce/fir/pine lumber used as fencing rails to stand up as long as 2x6 redwood in a climate (northern New Mexico) with the following characteristics?

- 105 °F heat in the summer
- 15 °F cold in the winter
- Intensely sunny nearly year-round (mile high elevation)
- Very little moisture; rot not a concern
- Subterranean termites

And if the redwood will last longer, in what way?

Comment: Sufficient how? What's your desired service life?

Comment: As long as possible. 20 years minimum.

Comment: Cedar will last a very long time exposed in a dry climate. Cedar has a much better appearance than spruce/pine, and is cheaper than redwood.